# how do i blur background behind the text

Tags: html, css, background, blur

Can anyone help me find what's the mistake in doing here? I am trying to bring the text above the background but if i used `z-index: -1;` it will disappear or just go to the back and won't be able to see it. and also wont mind to say if there's a better way to reform all the that code.

```css
html, body {margin:0;padding:0}

.page-title {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 38%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

.hero-title {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 40px;
}

.hero-title::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.text-wraper {
  z-index: 700;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-title {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1pt;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sub-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image">
  <span class="deskTop1280">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x500/246D5F" width="100%" alt="">
  </span>
</div>
<div class="page-title">
  <div class="hero-title">
    <div class="text-wraper">
      <div class="main-title">Main title goes here</div>
      <div class="sub-title">sub title goes here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I sinceriously can't understand what you're trying to do there.. Please clarify

Comment: check the second answer! im trying to blur the text background.

Comment: what text, above which background? and what's the part the you need blured? and what does Z-index has to do with any of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for z-index to take effect, it needs to be accompanied by a position rule like so:

```
.text-wraper {
  z-index: 700;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You actually don't need the z-index on .text-wraper. I've put together an example at: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMLveE?editors=1100.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you're trying to blur the background image like this?

EDIT, here's also the text in the front, you where using z-index 1 instead of -1 :
https://jsfiddle.net/qrz19v00/1/

I just added a class to the image with the blur property:

```
.blur_image {
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Comment: Nope! I'm trying to blur the text background not the image

Comment: @Arsaar You're trying to blur the "1280 x 500" text that the image background has on it? That doesn't look possible since it is an image. It'll be better to make that image yourself with code instead of loading it as an image itself.. If not, I don't really understand the question and I'd suggest to clarify it.

Comment: check the second answer!

Comment: @Arsaar Right, didn't understood the question. It was simple, you can also acomplish that by setting your page-title max width to 100%... Good luck!